# How to work with enums in C# generated by SWIG from C code?

Tags: c#, c, swig

Here is my C enum:

```
typedef enum {
    VALUE1,
    VALUE2,
    VALUE3
} myenum;
```

Here is one of my C functions:

```
myenum getEnumValue1() { 
    return VALUE1; 
}
```

I was expecting to get something like this in C#:

```
public enum SWIGTYPE_p_myenum {
    VALUE1,
    VALUE2,
    VALUE3
}
```

Indeed, the function wrapper was generated, and it returns something called myenum, but I see no mention of VALUE1, etc.

How can I work with the C# wrapper?  I'd like to do comparisons, assignments, pass these values into functions, etc., but I don't see any way to do it.

For example, I can't do the following:

```
SWIGTYPE_p_myenum x = SWIGTYPE_p_myenum.VALUE1; 
bool test = (x == SWIGTYPE_p_myenum.VALUE1);
```

There just isn't wrapper code that's generated that makes that possible.  This is all that gets generated:

```
public class SWIGTYPE_p_myenum {
  private global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef swigCPtr;

  internal SWIGTYPE_p_myenum(global::System.IntPtr cPtr, bool futureUse) {
    swigCPtr = new global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef(this, cPtr);
  }

  protected SWIGTYPE_p_myenum() {
    swigCPtr = new global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef(null, global::System.IntPtr.Zero);
  }

  internal static global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef getCPtr(SWIGTYPE_p_myenum obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? new global::System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef(null, global::System.IntPtr.Zero) : obj.swigCPtr;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try it without `typedef`'ing the enum.

Comment: Aha!  The C# enum is generated now.  But, it is empty:

public enum SWIGTYPE_myenum {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the SWIG [docs](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.1/HTML/SWIG.html#n2):

> For enumerations, it is critical that the original enum definition be included somewhere in the interface file (either in a header file or in the %{,%} block). SWIG only translates the enumeration into code needed to add the constants to a scripting language. It needs the original enumeration declaration to retrieve the correct enum values.

Make sure that you are "parsing" the header file, as well as including it:

```
 %module example
 %{
 /* Includes the header in the wrapper code */
 #include "header.h"
 %}

 /* Parse the header file to generate wrappers */

 %include "header.h"  <== don't forget this part
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  I did have to refactor my header file because SWIG was giving me the infamous "Error: Syntax error in input(1)" for reasons unknown on another enum (not the one I was trying to get).